# How to aggregate strings in multiple rows in IBM InfoSphere DataStage grouped by a given ID

Tags: etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I am given a table like the following of a attendece of employees at a company. The data should be extracted from a sequenctial file which has comma seperated values.

| ID | Weekday | Attendence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monday | Yes |
| 2 | Monday | Yes |
| 3 | Monday | No |
| 4 | Monday | Yes |
| 1 | Tuesday | Yes |
| 2 | Tuesday | No |
| 3 | Tuesday | Yes |
| 4 | Tuesday | Yes |

ID column has the employee ID and Weekday and Attendence columns has the exact meaning. I wan to count how many days the employee has shown up and I want the Days he attended as a comma seperated list. Like below

| ID | Weekday_List | Attendenc_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monday,Tuesday | 2 |
| 2 | Monday | 1 |
| 3 | Tuesday | 1 |
| 4 | Monday,Tuesday | 2 |

Comment: I did this using the sql when the data is on a database using the SQL db2 "select id, substr(listagg(weekday,','),1,60) weekdays, count(attendence) daynumber from rantab where Attendence='Yes' group by id" but I have no idea how to do this using an aggregator or a transformer stage.

Comment: The aggregator stage is not much of use to aggregate the list as there is no string function that can be used with the aggregator stage.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a transformer stage as concat aggregation is not supported by the aggregator stage.

You could use stage variables to do it or a transformer loop.
The loop example shown [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=loops-loop-example-aggregating-data) can be changed to do a concat.

If you decide to try it without the loop you need:

- sorted and partitioned input to the transformer
- use LastRowInGroup() to reset the string after each ID (and a second stage variable)

Comment: I will try and let you know.